# как синхронизировать базу данных mongodb, сервер nodejs

Tags: база-данных, node.js, веб-программирование, mongodb

Я впервые столкнулся с базой данных, ни с какими не имел дел, ни с какими.
смотрел урок, мне так легче воспринимать информацию, установил на комп windows-10 mongodb, создал на диске "С" папку data в ней папку db. абсолютно идентичные  действия были произведены на ноутбуке, тоже windows 10. ниже привожу пример кода на сервере. сервер nodejs

```
    var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    id3 = require('id3js'),
    Router = require('routes'),
    getFilesName = require('./myModule/getFilesName'),
    async = require('async');
var app = express();

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/datadb', function(err, database) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err)
    }
    db = database;
    app.listen(8001);
});


var server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());



app.get('/loadMusic', function(req, res) {
    var arrayString = getFilesName('./binary/sounds/Truba/');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(arrayString);
});
```

код между двумя компами синхронизируется посредством git.
и тут меня осенило, git синхронизирует  определенную папку. например,

G:\Project\test_nodejs
 а база на диске "С"
C:\data\db

на уроке использовали сторонний сервис https://mlab.com/

вот у меня и созрел вопрос, как в случае если не хочешь использовать сторонние сервисы, синхронизируется база данных локально между двумя компьютерами?

Сейчас пищу вопрос и думаю, может создать новый репозиторий на git   просто его синхронизировать отдельно?

P.S.  и без флешки и локальной сетки....

Comment: Может с ноута просто подключаться к той, что на компе запущена?

Comment: как? я впервые седня создал базу...  вообще не имею представления как база синхронизируется

Comment: не прошу ни каких примеров, просто подскажи что читать и куда двигаться

Comment: Также как и к локальной скорей всего, разве что вместо localhost пишете ip адрес (внутренней сети) компа.

Comment: дома 4 компа, а у меня даже локальной сетки нет... это локальную сетку надо иметь... не вариант

Comment: Т.е. git у вас не по сетке синхронизирует код?

Comment: Как вариант - экспортируете на одном компе базу, импортируете на другом, переносите на флешке.

Comment: нет,  не по сетке, а на bitbucket. впервые слышу что бы по домашней сетке git синхронизировался

Comment: спасибо конечно что отозвался, но переносить с помощью флешки я сам мог сообразить)))))

Comment: Подключи к проекту базу данных, как сервис https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas?jmp=nav или https://mlab.com/

Comment: спасибо, я об этих вариантах знаю, просто хочу знать как это делается без флешки и сторонних сервисов...

Comment: может объясните почему вопрос следует закрыть?

Comment: двое за закрытие вопроса, один из них еще и отрицательный статус влепил... а может это кто то третий...  что не так с вопросом?

Comment: 3 голоса из 5 за закрытие - это еще не закрытие. Могу посоветовать максимально детализировать вопрос - что, где, куда. Сейчас вопрос слишком размытый. Короткий вопрос и куча уточняющих комментариев под ним - это верный признак, что с вашим вопросам что-то не так. Всю дополнительную информацию из комментариев вносите в вопрос.

Comment: щас, постараюсь...

Comment: Коллеги из очереди проверки на закрытие. Если кто увидит вопрос -- [не торопитесь добавить свой голос за закрытие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5875/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2), дайте топикстартеру немного времени.